# Django: Raw sql INSERT INTO phpbb db fails: Error #1062 Duplicate key

Tags: sql, django, phpbb, duplicates

Hey,
I'm having a signal when a django user is created I manually insert that user into a phpbb table as well. The code follows:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_created_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user = kwargs['instance']

        fields = {
            'username': str(user.username),
            'username_clean': str(user.username),
            'user_password': "",
            'user_email': str(user.email),
            'group_id': 7,
            'user_timezone': 0,
            'user_dst': "",
            'user_lang': "sv",
            'user_type': 0,
            'user_actkey': "",
            'user_ip': "",
            'user_regdate': "",
            'user_inactive_reason': "",
            'user_inactive_time': "",
            'user_permissions': 0,
            'user_sig': "",
            'user_form_salt': "gg54jhg345",
        }
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Add user to phpbb

        try:

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO spelutveckla_se.phpbb_users " + str(tuple(fields.keys())).replace("'", "") + " VALUES" + str(tuple(fields.values())))

        except Warning:
            pass
```

I keep get this error message:
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'test_username' for key 'username_clean'")

I can see in the phpbb_user table that the user has been created. But when I remove the user and try again the same error appears. I've tried with different user names as well. It's like the code is executed more than once but I've tried to put breakpoints/raised exception to fins out but I can't find any sign of the code being executed more than once...

Here's the SQL:

> "INSERT INTO
>   spelutveckla_se.phpbb_users (username,
>   user_timezone, user_form_salt,
>   username_clean, user_dst, user_lang,
>   user_password, user_sig, user_type,
>   user_actkey, user_ip,
>   user_permissions, user_regdate,
>   group_id, user_inactive_reason,
>   user_email, user_inactive_time)
>   VALUES('test_username', 0,
>   'gg54jhg345', 'test_username', '',
>   'sv', '', '', 0, '', '', 0, '', 7, '',
>   'test@gmail.com', '')

Please help!! Thank you.

Comment: You're running into a problem with auto-increment. Even when you delete the newest row, auto-increment starts at 1+latest row. This is by design. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/mysql-auto-increment-after-delete . The second entry on the list may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had similar problem. I moved code that adds signal to another `__init.py__` file. For ex. from `__init__`  inside yourapp, to init file in root project folder (or inversely). Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Wow, can't belive I spend so many hours on this s*hit :)