# Fixing gaps in mysql table row id after we delete some of them

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with more than 17000 rows in it. And I have deleted about 530 rows from some mid part of it. Now each row had a sequential AUTO-INCREAMENTED number primary key. As you can understand now several numbers for rows have been deleted. So i just wanted to ask that is there any way to fix all rows again in some flawless order?

Comment: I just wonder why would you ever need to do this? How do gaps in the `id` column matter anyway except when your counter is about to reach the limit[well, for that you should start thinking about using a GUID].

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2214209/1839439

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can **but be carefull** of other tables using this primary key as a foreign key

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE table SET table.id = @count:= @count + 1;
```

this will update the `id` column of the table `table` ... you then need to reset the auto_increment :

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

This resets the next id to be `MAX(id)+1` from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) :

> To change the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT counter to be used for new
>   rows, do this:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
> ```
>
> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal
>   to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value
>   is reset to the current maximum plus one

Comment: +1 great 1 liner query.  I just wonder why would anyone ever need to do this? How do gaps in the `id` column matter anyway except when your counter is about to reach the limit[well, for that you should start thinking about using a GUID].

Comment: That code can be applied to other tables at the SAME TIME in case of id as foreign key, Are there other risks? the `other tables` is not an issue for me.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` is not needed with INNODB.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple fix for this with php, i just tested it out.

```
$count = 0;  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         $count++;
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET id='".$count."' WHERE id='".$row['id']."'"); 
         }
```