# Cascading Number MySQL

Tags: mysql, cascade

Ok I'm new with MySQL so excuse any stupid questions and such but I'm having a problem with the simple database table I created.

See: [image]

I have it set up so each new entry has a automatically incrementing `id` however if I were to delete the third row, there is a gap. I have heard that there is a way to cascade the other numbers down when a previous entry is deleted. I have looked but couldn't find anything that would help me change it in phpMyAdmin without recreating the table.

How would I do this?

Comment: Why do you mind gaps in the list of ids?

Comment: @VMai For what I'm doing, I need them to cascade down. It's rather hard to explain without showing you my entire script.

Comment: You don't. It is very bad idea to update primary keys. This ID could be already copied to different tables and databases. Updating them is complicated and completely useless process. If you want to maintain some kind of "sorting" you can do it in query time.

Comment: @AndrewFrolov I only have the one table as this is a very small project just for me to learn but I need it to cascade.

Comment: The first thing you should have learned now is that such an idea is a bad idea. You could do it in query time, as Andrew mentioned.

Comment: "I have it set up so each new entry has a automatically incrementing id" This statement is a lie!

Comment: Please have a look at post here, are you trying to ac :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/mysql-auto-increment-after-delete

Comment: @Spedwards There is no automated way to do it. And I strongly discourage you to do it :) Consider this as a lesson from your small learning project :)

Answer (score 3):

This question pops up every once in a while, and there's this confusion that `auto_increment` gives you sequential numbers that you can use, well, for sequences. You can't.

The sole purpose of primary key is to **uniquely** identify a row. And incrementing integer fits that role perfectly, it's easy to implement in C/C++ MySQL code and it works extremely fast and well.

But that's all it does. You don't get nice, sequential numbering feature out of it. You can't use it for what you want because there are, as you called it - gaps.

And no, you don't make MySQL fill the gaps. It's bad and it's dangerous and it creates problems that you didn't even think of.

Bottom line is that you **never rely** on `auto_increment` to reuse "wasted" numbers.

Here's why:

InnoDB, default MySQL engine, uses the primary key internally to physically organize records on the hard drive. It relies on the feature that every *next* id is greater than one before. I won't get into details, but the key idea is that the index and data are written on the same page. That makes InnoDB extremely fast when doing primary key lookups (`SELECT col FROM table WHERE id = 1000000` types of queries).

Now, what happens when you "reuse" the keys that had gaps - imagine this scenario: you have 1 million records. There were no number losses. 
You delete the record 500 000. 
Afterwards, you add new record, and using your logic - you need to "reuse" number 500 000. So you do it.
But, InnoDB expects every next record to be larger. So to conform to your needs, it has to rebalance what it has written. And it has to start from record 500 000. Now you have 500 000 records that are being reorganized, and that means you have 500 000 checks and writes going on. This kills your performance, COMPLETELY. Let's say you have a mechanical hard drive. It's capable of about 200-300 input output operations per second (IOPS). If every reorganized record requires 1 I/O, to reorganize 500 000 of them would take 20-30 minutes. Now you have inserts that take 30 minutes to complete.

The other problem, much more severe than the performance problem is concurrency and isolation problem.
What people don't understand is that MySQL (and other relational databases) solve the problem of concurrency, or if you will - problem of simultaneous access or "What happens when two users write at the same time" problem. 
MySQL takes care of that, and even more. And the feature where it "wastes" numbers is what actually makes it happen. Every transaction relies on the primary key at one point. Even before you commit the transaction, an auto_increment was already assigned to it. So even when transaction fails or isn't commited, an auto_increment gets "wasted". It's actually DESIRABLE behavior.

I definitely didn't list all the disadvantages, just two that I could think of (I also didn't describe them in detail due to lack of time but principles do apply).

Conclusion is - **do not "reuse" wasted auto_increment numbers, do not listen to people who tell you how to do it, do not assume that your project won't have problems I listed above. If you do, prepare to encounter problems you could never think of**.