# reuse missing id (auto_increment) in mysql innodb table

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I have a table in magento where many records will be deleted (about 50k rows).
I need to make id as little as possible as it's used as reference to records, so I want to reuse deleted ids.
Could you tell me how to reuse id reliably in multiuser enviroment?'
I tried to make trigger that set id if there any ids to reuse:

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `product_BINS`    BEFORE INSERT ON `product`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE reused_id integer;
    DECLARE semaphore_id integer;

```
SET @semaphore_id = (SELECT id FROM semaphore WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE);
SET @reused_id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM product_all_ids LEFT JOIN product ON id = product_id WHERE product_id IS NULL);

IF (NOT ISNULL(@reused_id)) THEN
    SET NEW.product_id = @reused_id;
END IF;
```

END

I use table semaphore like semaphore to avoid issues in multiuser system. I tried to test it and haven't found any issues so far.
Does it make sense? Is it a viable solution?

Comment: Why do you care how big the ids are?  If the ids are being used to reference to other tables, then it is a really bad idea to try to change them.

Comment: What you want to do is not a good practice. Please check this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/mysql-auto-increment-after-delete)

Comment: The problem  is ids are use to refer item when people communicate. The short this code - the better.