# Yii2 reset db ids when transaction rollback

Tags: transactions, yii2, rollback

I've noticed by transactions rollbacks, primary key ids keep growing. Is it possible somehow to reset them (auto increment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using [delete()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#delete%28%29-detail) in your `safeDown()` method. if you want to remove all data from the table, you should use [truncateTable()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#truncateTable%28%29-detail) or you can write your own slq with [execute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#execute%28%29-detail).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't truncate, but this question seems lame, according to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try set AUTO_INCREMENT to 1

```
public function down()
{
    $this->delete('{{%email}}', ['id' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,]]);
    $this->execute('ALTER TABLE {{%email}} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1');
    // When you insert any other (not NULL or 0) value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column,
    // the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the
    // next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value.
}
```