# codeigniter sort id after delete

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to rebuild id's after delete raw....

e.x

```
1 Text1 Number
2 Text2 Number
3 Text3 Number
4 Text4 Number
5 Text5 Number
```

Whan after delete raw 4. 
i want table look like:

```
1 Text1 Number
2 Text2 Number
3 Text3 Number
4 Text5 Number
```

And whan i add new item add to id 5

I work on codeigniter and my controller is:

delete function:

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM bookmark WHERE id = '$id'");
```

add function:

```
 $this->db->query("INSERT INTO bookmark VALUES ('$id', '$text', '$number')");
```

Answer (score 1):

After delete run this mysql command

```
SET @num := 0;

UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);

ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

In codeigniter active-records use as :-

```
$this->db->query("SET @num := 0;");
$this->db->query("UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);");
$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
```

Find more info here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745767/3568847)

Comment: it's possible to make this automatic after delete row? In codeigniter php code

Comment: I got this error:

http://prntscr.com/a2teti

Comment: Delete a row in phpmyadmin manually and run this query statement in phpmyadmin and tell me is it running fine there  ?