# Multi line statement in PHP to MySQL database (resorting auto incremented IDs)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little bit of a problem figuring out where the error comes from. 
The background is that I have a table and using a form I update the values into the table and can update them and delete them using different buttons.

This leaves the auto incremented IDs in disorder after deletion and I thought it would be just good practice to see if I could reset the order using a simple button.

Otherwise I've been updating them using

```
SET @num := 0;

UPDATE tableName SET id = @num := (@num+1);

ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

in phpmyadmin. I got it from this answer :
[Auto Increment after delete in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql#answer-28745767)

```
//resort database
if(isset($_POST['resort'])){

// Database connection opening
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','powerstations');  //our server, the username, the password (empty), the database itself
    if($mysqli) {
        echo "Connected!";
        } else {
    echo "Problem.";
}


$sql_resort = "SET @num := 0; ";
$sql_resort .= "UPDATE powerdata SET id = @num := (@num+1); ";
$sql_resort .= "ALTER TABLE powerdata AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; ";

if ($mysqli->query($sql_resort) === TRUE) {
    echo "Resorted successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql_resort . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

The error I get is:
 SET @num := 0; UPDATE powerdata SET id = @num := (@num+1); ALTER TABLE powerdata AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE powerdata SET id = @num := (@num+1); ALTER TABLE powerdata AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1

I tried to search for typos by putting the multi line statement into phpmyadmin, but found nothing and I don't see where the problem with the "code structure" is if there is one.

Comment: Just leave the ids alone that is not a good practice at all. You will end up having to update large swatches if say you delete 3 out of 5000. Not to mention what that would do to your FK.

Comment: I understood from the previous thread that resetting IDs is not a good practice, but this is more of personal lesson to understand PHP and MySQL for me and I have problems figuring out what I don't understand

Comment: you can't issue multiple statements in a single query() call. it's a limitation in the underlying mysql driver as a basic defense against one form of sql injection attack. You have to do each statement as its OWN `query()` call.

Comment: Okay, I thought it was possible from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php but this is in other words different?
How do I split up the query so that it remembers, for example @num?
I tested running one line at a time in phpmyadmin but that didn't work

Comment: No but `$mysqli->query` would need to be `$mysqli->multi_query($sql)` like the manual shows.

Comment: Alright, will try, I'll be back in a while :)

Edit: Alright: Worked, tyvm!

Comment: Since this is about MySQL instead of Microsoft SQL Server, I have edited your tags to remove the tag for MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting do execute multiple statements in a single query you have to call `$mysqli->multi_query($sql)` not `$mysqli->query($sql)`.

So you will need to update

```
if ($mysqli->query($sql_resort) === TRUE) {}
```

to

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql_resort) === TRUE) {
```