# Reset table's AUTO_INCREMENT in php

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I have a database which must maintain a strict primary key numerical sequence in its `id` column. i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

Now when I delete a row I then need to do a recount and an increment reset using:

```
SET @count = 0; 
UPDATE `Main` 
SET `id` = @count:= @count + 1; 
ALTER TABLE Main 
AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

This works fine when typed into the MySQL command line and is exactly what I want however I need to execute it from a PHP script command. I use:

```
$sql="SET @count = 0"; 
$result=$database->query($sql);
$sql="UPDATE Main SET id = @count:= @count + 1"; 
$result=$database->query($sql);
$sql="ALTER TABLE Main AUTO_INCREMENT =1"; 
$result=$database->query($sql);
```

Now the first two recount lines work fine but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` line will not reset the auto increment counter. Again `"ALTER TABLE Main AUTO_INCREMENT =1;"` works fine directly from the MySQL command line but not when executed through the PHP script.

Note: the database uses the `mysqli_query` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Increment after delete in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql)

Comment: Try running them all in the same line: ```$sql="SET @count = 0; UPDATE `Main` SET `id` = @count:= @count + 1; ALTER TABLE Main AUTO_INCREMENT =1;"```

Comment: No, I did try this before and again just now but it doesn't even do the recount of the primary key. I've also tried replacing semicolons with commas and different punctuations etc...

Comment: I've tried setting AUTO_INCREMENT to 0 as well as other numbers (even high numbers) and this command just does not affect the actual increment counter using PHP but it does using MySQL command line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it.
AUTO_INCREMENT resides in the "information_schema.tables" database and my user had "USAGE" only privileges for this table. With the "ALTER" privilege granted it works fine.
Thanks.