# How to block mysql auto increment filed if data is not save in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am create table and made ID field is auto increment
When I delete the row, the ID continues after the deleted row id
OR How sort ID after remove some rows 
Example
When I delete the row ID 38 and then add a row that stores ID 39 not 38
this mean 
id is not sort 
How to block mysql increase when Do that ?

Comment: My opinion is : you do not solve this. It is not a problem ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto Increment after delete in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql)

Comment: Don't confuse auto incremented ID with a consecutive numbering. IDs do not need to be contiguous.