# How to Reset Autoincrement ID to the previous ID

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I just need a logic on how to Reset Autoincremented ID to the previous ID which I deleted recently from database for example I just delete ID=3 from database next time I add data into database ID will be incremented to 4 and it will be showed as 1 2 4 but I dont want 4 I want it to be 3 Im building a small inventory management system using php and sql.

Comment: If you use PHPMyAdmin you can set the AUTO_INCREMENT under the Operations tab of your table. If you need to do it with a query it would be something like `ALTER TABLE foobar AUTO_INCREMENT = 123`

Comment: What is the purpose of such an requirement?

Comment: This is depending on your database. What kind of database do you use? Please provide us with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will set your AUTO_INCREMENT value to 1 less than what it currently is, however I would recommend you don't bother doing so - recycling key values is not recommended practice and can be risky as it's not the way AUTO_INCREMENT is intended to be used (see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql)).

```sql
ALTER TABLE TableName AUTO_INCREMENT =
(SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName') - 1;
```