# Incorrect auto increment using fetch POST after manually deleted data from table

Tags: mysql

i created REST API and website which is using it. There is database and inside it table with columns id and room. Id have turned on auto increment. I have a button that create ticket by fetch and method post. Inside body there is only room number "101". I deleted manually tickets from table that i created before by pressing button and my tickets table is empty. But when i press button then it doest create ticket with is 1... there is id 91, 92... I dont know how to reset this counting. Please help me. Sorry for my English. Here is my fetch script that create ticket.

```
`<script>
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
const room = {
room: 101,
}
console.log(room)
fetch('http://localhost/tickets', {
method: "POST",
headers: {
'Content-type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify(room),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
})
function visitPage(){
window.location='room_101.html';
return room;
}
</script>`
```

I dont know how to solve the problem. Is it api problem or js? I dont know what to do.

Comment: There are nothing to do with this issue with PHP, and it's better to keep the database auto increment as is. here is some explanation for why you need to keep the auto increment as is [Auto Increment after delete in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql)

Comment: Just a warning, there is rarely a technical need to reset the auto increment. In pretty much every case I’ve seen, it is a human factor, where someone doesn’t like that an empty database isn’t starting at `1`, or something like that

Comment: I used  ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = value;, but it didnt work. I also have in my console information "This value was evaluated upon first expanding. It may have changed since then"

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to JS or JSON after all?

Comment: No, im not sure :(

Comment: “didn’t work” - did you get an error message?

Comment: No, i didnt get error. I mean it didnt solve problem. I used this statement in phpmyadmin console and was executed

Comment: Keep in mind that all clarification should be part of your question

Comment: It doesn't matter what the number is. Its just a number used as an ID. As long as its unique it's irrelevant whether it starts at 1 or 1 million.  Resetting it rarely serves any meaningful purpose

Comment: I had to delete all records in my DB and then use ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value; - it solved my problem

Comment: As explained above, you didn't actually have a problem, you just _thought_ you had a problem. You don't _need_ to ever reset the count. The actual numbers being used don't matter, as long as they're unique.